# Should clothing be photographed hanging or on the floor? And how should I set up my lighting?

Tags: product-photography, studio-setup

I'm starting out in product photography & someone asked me to shoot some clothing for them- we checked out a couple of clothing sites to see what we like and found [this site](http://www.patagonia.com)
that has some really good looking images i would like to copy like the image below-

[image: pix]

Does anyone have an idea how these pictures were taken & what they used to give dimension to the clothes so that they don't look dead? 
Any tips on the light setup?- (in my studio I'm currently using a set of 2 strobes with softboxes or scrims & various light stands (-would like tips on how to use strobes not constant light)

I do not want to do the ghost mannequin effect shown [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/how-to-do-the-ghost-mannequin-effect) as it is not practical, considering the amount of clothes that I need to photograph for a new website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everyone prefers to see the clothing's fitting so , a model wearing the outfit is the most aesthetic way to subject the product.

any product shoot has 
1) the main subject
2) the contrasting element to enhance the subject
3) and minor key elements

make sure you use all 3 to make a perfect product photography. check out any product, almost all of them have these 3 factors as subjects.

and shoot. unless you are on a very tight budget.(you can still get your friends to wear them and pose as models)..... :)

Answer (score 1):

So, this is a bit of a guess on my part, but if I was to try tackling this I would:

1. Use a light tent, that helps with the fairly even lighting, but with just enough to create a shadow and that adds to depth.
2. If I didn't have a light tent, I would probably use some seamless white paper and lay out the clothing on that. I think it's lying flat, so you may need to use a chair or ladder to go above it.
3. I can't be sure, but it may be a single light set up, high and to the top left a bit. The shadows on the right are pretty small, so it may also be a bit of fill from the bottom right. Either way, a nice softbox is going to give soft, even, lighting. You may want to experiment with the strength of the light(s) and the distances a bit. It's not like your model will complain, so take a bunch of shots. :)
4. As for filling out the clothing a bit... I'd probably use bubble wrap or something similar. The wrap with the really big bubbles, which you could probably get from a company such as U-Haul that supports the moving industry, might just do the trick nicely. It's probably what I would try, maybe cut to shape and placed inside. Not a lot of dimension, but it give some, as this image appears to do.

In terms of the strobes, go ahead and experiment, the softboxes will do what's need to soften and even things out. I don't know what camera you have, so remote control of the strobes I can't advise on, other than if you're using the built-in flash of the camera as a commander, take it out of the mix with your menu settings and just let it fire the signal and ***not*** join in the light. Shoot manual too, don't let the camera pick.

Anyways, that's some ideas. Perhaps others can chime in.