# How are these clothes pictures being photographed?

Tags: product-photography, background

[image: children's clothing set display]

I want to know how these clothing sets are being photographed? is it on hangers or on the ground? How can I blow out the background completely like this?

Comment: Hard to tell if it's on the ground or hanging from such a small image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do the ghost mannequin effect?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/how-to-do-the-ghost-mannequin-effect)

Comment: @MikeW - I thought that too, but they didn't looked filled in, so I think the question is more about the background.

Comment: JoanneC: they do look kinda flat don't they, so probably not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are being photographed using the "Ghost Mannequin" technique or a slight variant of it.

Usually clothes are placed on a mannequin, photographed and then photographed again inside-out.  The two images are then put together in post-processing.  In this case they may have varied it slightly by placing the clothes out flat, but broadly the technique looks the same.

For more see here: [How to do the ghost mannequin effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/how-to-do-the-ghost-mannequin-effect)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's photographed on a ground (noticed that everything is flat), most likely from a height (ladder/stairs/window on a 1st floor ;) ) on a large sheet of white paper/cloth (either laying horizontally or at a slight angle).

Considering how evenly lit the clothes are I guess photographer used 2 flashes standing on a sides with either umbrellas or (more likely) large reflectors / softboxes. There are several light setups that can be used for such effect.

In either case - it looks like a rather professional setup.