# How to achieve great clothing photography with natural wrinkles effect

Tags: lighting, online-shopping, photo-shoot, clothing

We are wondering how these photos of apparel are taken, as they are trending.

[image]

It is not the typical flat lay shots, as the garment shows some texture and it is somehow "inflated" from the inside.

How should the garment be positioned to achieve this effect?

Comment: Related: [how to do the ghost mannequin effect](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/how-to-do-the-ghost-mannequin-effect)

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is not a ghost mannequin as the garment still looks pretty flat, just a little bit of inflation/texture

Comment: Agreed, this question is definitely not a duplicate of that other one. Still, it might be useful for people searching for answers about this in the future. As for your question, I unfortunately don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The shirt is most likely not inflated. The shadow can be easily made in Photoshop.

Prepare a cardboard inside the shirt at the proper dimensions. Another for the neck, the same type as some shirts on an original package.

The main light is not very difused, but it has a very difused fill light.

*Edited.*

Just buy a corrugated sheet. https://www.google.com/search?q=corrugated put your shirt on it, draw the contours and cut.

For the neck, you can use the small plastic pices that come with some new shirts.

Comment: Any site that shows how to prepare such cardboard? That might be the key...

Comment: I edited the post. Not that complicated.

Comment: The shadow is quite certainly added in Photoshop or similar editing software. It's hard to imagine a lighting setup which would result in that last shape.

Comment: A hard key light directly overhead (to the right of the collar as viewed here sideways) at a fairly acute angle and a very diffuse fill light aimed just below the collar could achieve this without any "Photoshop" beyond global contrast and light curves adjustments.