# Why can't I get a decent white background for my product photography

Tags: dslr, lighting, background, studio

This is the example image i have taken this few days.
[image: I'm using a stable tripod, low iso, small aperture, slow shutter to get the background over exposed.]

why can't I get the full white background like the photo from the internet?

[image: I had already place the light pointing at the back but still having black corners![][2]]

Comment: That is pretty good I would say! Now, if you want to ask for help, sure but let us know what you did so that we can start guessing at what to improve.

Comment: If you mean the darkened corner, you just need more even lighting.  Looks pretty good.  If there's a dark area, throw light on it.  Or you can easily fix that in post.

Comment: Have you looked at related questions? e.g. http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14991/how-do-i-properly-do-shadowless-product-photos?rq=1

Comment: I'm with the rest, what's the problem with that? The corner is easy to fix, the rest looks great.

Comment: Duplicate **question title** with [Why can't I get a decent white background with product photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38343/17441) which also has good answers there.

Comment: notice how the upper right corner of the supposed pure white background is also slightly darker :)

Comment: these questions are very common here.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: You need more light on the background so that you can intentionally blow it out without blowing out the product. Then expose so that the background is on the verge of blowing out. In post-processing push the exposure for the highlights up until the background is pure white.

This has been covered many times here in the past:

[How do I improve the results of photos taken in a light-box?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40747/15871)
[Why hasn't buying powerful lights improved my lightbox images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42681/15871)
[How do I properly do shadowless product photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14991/15871)
[Why can't I get a decent white background with product photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38343/15871)