# (compression artefacts) Pixelated photo, using Canon EOS T6 dslr

Tags: pixels

So I bought the Canon EOS rebel T6 to take pictures of products and the result is not clean as I expected.

See below a picture crudely cropped for space requierement of this site.
I took this picture in close mode wiht the flower icon.

[image]

I tried to fix this problem during about 10 hours so this is what

I have tried:
Each mode of the camera, including many manual settings.
post modification with photoshop and RAW plugins

Not tried yet:
Adding more light to the scene.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The image is very heavily compressed at 230Kb for an 8Mp image and showing lots of compression artefacts which is what you might be referring to by 'pixellated'. What was the aperture, shutter speed and ISO of that image? What are the JPEG settings in camera or in your photo-editing program?

Comment: 1/125 F6.3 Iso AUTO, but I took this photo with thw close up mode­. I havent investigated compression. Thx for help. This photo is not edited, editing it doesnt fix the problem. About the camera settings all I can say is Raw + Large jpeg (I tried RAW editing) 18 M 5184*3456

Comment: How can I fix the compression?

Comment: Mark - IU assume you are somehow editing and saving the photo. The 'Large JPEG' out of the camera would be 5-6Mb in size. Can you tell us what you do to the photo after you copy it from the camera?

Comment: @SteveIves I'm taking picture of products that I'm going to sell online, that's the main goal. The photo above is not edited, I uploaded it from the sd card of the camera. There is some compression artefats wich is not normal. I plan resizing the image in photoshop to 1800 x 1200. Shooting in lower format doesnt fix the problem

Comment: I don't see any pixelization and very little compression. What I do see is a lot of chrominance noise as a result of underexposing the white background by letting the camera attempt to make it medium grey.

Comment: @MichaelClark Very interresting what you are saying here, but I have no real idea how to fix it. I'll do some reseach, otherwise what should I do?

Comment: I tired changing the background without much success.

Comment: Have you tried to set EV a bit higher? +1 perhaps. The blown background doesn't mind in that case or can be "photoshopped". Thsi cannot be set in Auto mode, but P-mode allows full auto with some customisation. Also do not take the picture when perpendicular to the screen; I can see your "ghost" on the screen.

Comment: @Mark Please see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43220/why-cant-i-get-a-decent-white-background-for-my-product-photography/43221#43221 and the links to other questions that the answer contains.

Comment: thx for replies, I tried with a lower ISO and the flash, the result is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be an exact answer, because we do not have any idea of what are you doing.

I will just gess.

- You are not using flash or you are using a very low power.
- You are boosting the ISO. Probably beyond 1600.
- Or you are using a long exposition to compensate the low light.

What you are seeing is NOT pixelation, is noise. And it is because the poor camera has little light to work with.

- Lower your ISO to 100 - 200.
- Use a flash or a strong light source.

---

Offtopic. If you are trying to sell your images online, it is ok. But you still have a long way to go: Specially on Ilumination and composition.

Comment: I found out yesterday. Thx for help. That is exactly the solution