# Color replacement Photoshop

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

I want to see how wood kitchen cabinets would look painted white. I've selected an area, and made a layer via `Copy> Desaturated> New Fill Layer>Solid color> multiply>` and selected white...and the Color replacement tool still makes the cabinets grey. I'm using PhotoshopCS6 Extended.

I've attached the photo I'm trying to edit. I want to make the kitchen cabinets white while preserving the grain of the wood. (Thanks to all who replied; I'm new to this site so bear with me if my replies aren't in the correct spot).

[image: kitchen 582]

Comment: Do you mind uploading the original for us to see what you're working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop's color replacement tool changes to grey (instead of white) — how can I change a grey background to pure white?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83513/photoshops-color-replacement-tool-changes-to-grey-instead-of-white-how-can)

Comment: The reason I ask for the original is because I find color replacement not really the best tool in the bag. Starting from the original gives people the ability to solve your problem with a method that they see fit - which may expose you to new tools and processes and is, overall, a much better way to get an answer.

Comment: Also - Multiply is a part of the "dark" modifiers. This link should give you an idea of why it's not working using multiply: https://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/layer-blend-modes/multiply/

Comment: Does the link I provided solve your problem?

Comment: The article is confusing- so i should NOT use Multiply? Opacity is 100% (apologies, I am an "elemental" photoshop user.)

Answer (score 1):

Done in Gimp, but I believe you can do the same with PS

- Add layer, set to "Grain merge" mode, reduce opacity (80%)
- Paint in white on layer (you can adjust opacity later)

[image]

Otherwise the [GraphicDesign site of SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/) could be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the "Opacity" bar, make it 100% on white and it will paint it in white instead of grey.

Comment: I believe my opacity bar is at 100%. It  would be awesome if you would send me all the steps to make the color replacement work as I have to look up the steps each time I try to make the tool work. thanks!